# Trouble writing a simple jQuery selector (used in firebug)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, firebug

I can't seem to select a particular element in a form. I can select all elements except the SELECT field. Strange...

I need to select the 'Choose a category' field from this page with FireQuery:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/

For example, this code works fine for the "Local Business or Place" section:

`$jq('#local_business_form > #local_business_form_page_name').val('test input');`

However this does not work:

`$jq('#local_business_form > #category').val('2518');`

Comment: Can you show the `HTML`

Comment: There's quite a bit of it, why not just view source?

Comment: you need to login for that

Comment: only the page header changes on login, it is the same form displayed

Comment: The only `#category` elements I see in that page's source are commented out.

Comment: you must view 'generated' page source, it's all built with JS, in firebug, just navigate to the form with the inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply dropping jQuery and using pure JS selectors.